# Where can I find the underlying xml for a CheckBoxPreference?

Tags: android, xml, listview, preferenceactivity, checkboxpreference

I would like to have a look at the various xml views (and specifically the CheckBoxPreference) that are inflated in the list view that makes up the PreferenceActivity. Where are the source code for these located?

I mean Android's source code for how they create the preference activity, not the xml I would use if I wanted to use a preference activity.

Comment: I mean Android's source code for how they create the preference activity, not the xml I would use if I wanted to use a preference activity.

Comment: You probably want this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.java

Comment: Yes, thanks! That was part of what I was looking for. Do you know where Android's layout xml for the CheckBoxPreference and other preference views are, too?

Comment: You probably look for this, too: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/res/res/layout/preference_widget_checkbox.xml